# Overwrite nested object in Elastic search partial update

Tags: elasticsearch

My index structure is

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "blogpost": {
        "properties": {
          "body": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "comments": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "age": {
                "type": "short"
              },
              "comment": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "stars": {
                "type": "short"
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

comments are nested objects. I want to update comment alone. But when I do partial update, ES is merging with existing comment object. I want to replace the existing comment with newer one. Is there anyway, We could configure ES to overwrite instead of merging nested object.

Comment: How are you doing your partial update?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this case?